# Embedded python interpreter fails to import c modules

Tags: python-2.7, gdb, windows-7-x64, mingw-w64

I have problems with the embedded python interpreter in gdborig.exe of the MinGW-w64 project (https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/discussion/723798/thread/4a8a9ed5/?limit=25).

The import of the module itertools and several others fails. But with the distributed standalone python interpreter the corresponding imports work fine:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.version
2.7.9 (default, Jul 11 2016, 16:32:13)
[GCC 6.1.0]
>>> print sys.executable
C:/AUEMARK/Programme/MinGW64/mingw64/opt/bin/python.exe
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools
<module 'itertools' from 'C:\AUEMARK\Programme\MinGW64\mingw64\opt\libpython2.7\lib-dynload/itertools.pyd'>
```

With the embedded python interpreter:

```
(gdb) python import sys
(gdb) python print sys.version
2.7.9 (default, Jul 11 2016, 16:32:13)
[GCC 6.1.0]
(gdb) python print sys.executable
C:/AUEMARK/Programme/MinGW64/mingw64/opt/bin/python.exe
(gdb) python import itertools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named itertools
Error while executing Python code.
```

Can:

- import sys
- import os

Can't:

- import itertools
- import collections
- ...

Error message for import of collections

```
(gdb) python import collections
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\AUEMARK\Programme\MinW64\mingw64\opt\lib\python2.7/collections.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _collections import deque, defaultdict
Importerror: no module named _collections
Error while executing Python code.
```

So it seems like the embedded interpreter cannot import modules in C. Python modules are imported, and the Python parts of C modules can be also accessed by the embedded interpreter.

Thanks for any hint, how I can solve this problem.

Markus

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem exists because file itertools.pyd was not found.
I had to set environment variable:

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python2.7;C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python2.7\lib-dynload;
```

In your case make sure you set:

```
PYTHONPATH=C:/AUEMARK/Programme/MinGW64/mingw64/opt/lib/python2.7;C:\AUEMARK\Programme\MinW64\mingw64\lib\python2.7\lib-dynload
```

My PYTHONHOME variable points to python interpreter:

```
PYTHONHOME=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\pyhon.exe
```

I built my own gdb under msys2 and it works:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.19]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\tiit>C:\msys64\home\tiit\gdb-7.11-bin\bin\x86_64-linux-gnu-gdb.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1.20160801-git
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb)
```

Without setting correct environment variables I had the same trouble.